# One Code Base but Different Images and External Data for iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I know there are other posts out there but I need a straight and best answer for this approach when using one project that will be reused, but just use different images and data.  This is a basketball tournament application that will make calls to an API and have a different Event ID and images with each application.  I want to reuse the same code base so when a bug is found I can make one update, and rebuild each target.  My question is where would I store the "`Event Id`" and "`Images`" separate from the source code in XCode?  This code base could be shared between 100s of applications.

Comment: What are you asking? Each app doesn't have different code... Same code on every phone

Comment: They share the same source code, just have different resources and an "Event ID".  The client will get their own application submitted to the app store.

Answer (score 2):

Create a different target for each. Then select what assets you want to include in each. The code can all be shared.

Comment: What about a specific piece of data like "Event ID"?

Comment: Create a constant (like DEBUG) in each of your targets and then use `#ifdef` to declare your variables based upon the target

Comment: One more question, if you specify each project, will it only copy over the images I specify in the target? or will it contain all images used by those multiple applications.  Also I assume the xcode project will contain all the image resources for all these projects.

Comment: No. Each target can specify which files to include or exclude.